# Getting error from undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')

Tags: react-native, mobile-application

I have been trying to find the solution to this error and it's troubling me. I created and bottom tab bar and nested a 2 tabs in one of the tab bar. When i created a button in the Main and called the main in GamePage , it couldn't get me to the intended screen. Any ideas?

[Game(Root) screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXxyA.png)

[stack navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0bOt.png)

[Main screen (nested in Root)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugybq.png)

Comment: please share the image

Comment: are you using react-navigation 5? can you also share your stack and or tab navigators

Comment: Hey, share some code to make yourself more clear man!

Comment: hi i've added an images , previously i did add images of my codes. But i've added them again since it wasn't able to be viewed earlier.

Comment: @DanielGonzalez yes i am using RN v5. I've added my images.

Answer (score 0):

@Chapffy this should help you navigate between stacks => https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators. Since `SendStack.Navigator` is nested inside the `MainPage.Navigator` when you want to navigate to this stack you need update your code to `navigation.navigate('send', { screen: 'gift' });`. The first argument is the screen inside `MainPage.Navigator` that contains the `SendStack.Navigator` and the second argument is the screen inside that navigator that you want to navigate too.